# Does the iOS Simulator have an ACAccount store by default?

Tags: ios

Does the iOS Simulator have an ACAccount store by default and can it be manipulated for testing the ACAccountStore and ACAccount APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to know if someone can use ACaccounts in their code, while testing on simulator.
Yes, We can use ACaccounts.

**To add account in Simulator:**

You can actually go to the Settings app on the iOS simulator and add the account - just like with the real handset.

**For instance, if someone wants to use all the twitter accounts:**

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init] ;
ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

if(twitterAccounts)
{
    NSLog(@"twitterAccounts: %@",twitterAccounts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this is backed by SQLite / Core Data? And can it be viewed as a table of data, even if requiring a third party tool?

Answer (score 0):

No.It does not have an ACAccount store by default.

**The ACAccountStore class provides an interface for accessing, manipulating, and storing accounts. To create and retrieve accounts from the Accounts database, you must create an ACAccountStore object. Each ACAccount object belongs to a single ACAccountStore object.**

For further details refer the apple developer forum - 
        https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/index.html